# substring in hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap, substring

I am trying to create a Map and use that Map later.
I am creating map like this.

```java
String line = "0010020 027071040YN Address Line 1";
Map.put(line.substring(0,8).toString(), line.substring(8).toString());
```

so my Map looks like `"0010020=027071040YN Address Line 1"`.

And it is working fine.But when i am trying to retrieve this entry from Map, i am not able to do it.
I am trying to retrieve like this:-

```
String temp= Map.get("0010020").toString();
```

The same thing is working fine if i don't use substring while putting data into Map. But i need to use substring. Please let me know how to proceed

Comment: Why are you calling `toString()` on the results of `substring()`? `substring()` already returns a `String`... And please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the space that comes after `0010020` in

```
0010020 027071040YN...
       ^ THIS
```

You are including the space in the `substring(0,8)` but not in the lookup.

In other words, the key in the map is `"0010020 "` whereas you're looking for `"0010020"`.

Comment: Thanks yaar..now it is working :)i had overlooked the substring index. when i passed index 0,7 i am getting my search. Thanks once again